# JavaScript: Array - возврат наименьшего и наибольшего значения из массива

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который принимает массив и должен вернуть отсортированный массив из двух элементов, первый - это наименьшее, второй наибольшее значение в передаваемом массиве. Логически сделал все верно но ни как не заставлю код работать. Помогите разобраться.

```js
function minMax(arr){
  function determineOrder(num){
    return (num[0] > num[1]) ? array.push(num[0], num[1]) : array.push(num[1], num[0]) ;
  }
  return arr.map(determineOrder);
}



minMaxminMax([1,2,3,4,5])  ;
```

А я ожидал такой результат:

```
minMax([1,2,3,4,5])   == [1,5]
minMax([2334454,5])   == [5, 2334454]
minMax([1])           == [1, 1]
```

Comment: Получаю какой то странный >Uncaught ReferenceError: minMaxminMax is not defined . Откуда появилось minMaxminMax?

Comment: вот из этой строчки: `minMaxminMax([1,2,3,4,5])  ;`

Comment: ну и сама функция делает не пойми что:)

Comment: es6: `const minmax = (a, m = Math) => [m.min(...a), m.max(...a)];` С подсказкой Grundy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без всяких заумностей. Внутри функции сначала определяем две переменные как минимум и максимум равные начальному элементу массива. Потом сравниваем их со всем элементами массива по порядку.

```js
function minMax(arr){
  var min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
  arr.forEach(function(val) {
    min = Math.min(min, val);
    max = Math.max(max, val);
  });
  return [min, max];
}

console.log(minMax([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(minMax([2334454,5]));
console.log(minMax([1]));
```

Answer (score 5):

Три представленные реализации возврщают наименьшее и наибольшее значения из массива

**es5:**

```js
function minMax(arr){
  return [Math.min.apply(Math, arr), Math.max.apply(Math, arr)];
}

console.log(minMax([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(minMax([2334454,5]));
console.log(minMax([1]));
```

**es6:**

```js
    function minMax(arr){
      return [Math.min(...arr), Math.max(...arr)];
    }

    console.log(minMax([1,2,3,4,5]));
    console.log(minMax([2334454,5]));
    console.log(minMax([1]));
```

**old way:**

```js
function minMax(arr) {
    var a = arr.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});
    return [a[0], a[a.length-1]];
  }

console.log(minMax([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(minMax([2334454,5]));
console.log(minMax([1]));
```

Comment: в новом стандарте все проще `[Math.min(...arr), Math.max(...arr)]`. Но этот код идет по массиву дважды, а в соседнем ответе - один раз

Comment: @Grundy , спасибо за ценные комментарии. Скажите, а почему проход по массиву дважды, затратнее операция, чем двойное сравнивание всех элементов ?  min = Math.min(min, val);
    max = Math.max(max, val);

Comment: На самом деле, я не сказал, что затратнее. Все зависит от нативной реализации. И возможной оптимизации созданного кода. Точно сказать что конкретный подход будет затратнее всегда, во всех браузерах - нельзя

Comment: Мне интересно почему лично вы отдаёте предпочтение коду, написанному уважаемым господином Visman'ом?

Comment: Например, потому что это самый очевидный вариант. Единственное, вместо forEach, можно было использовать for чтобы убрать вызов callback. Но тут уж как кому больше нравится